# Explanation for automatic tunneling attempt

Tags: web-application, ubuntu

I run a web forum built using Django, hosted on an Ubuntu 14.04 flavored VM. My users post comments and photos. Recently, a user left the following comments in one of the threads (as a verbal threat I assume, or peacocking to fellow users):

```
Connect to mystaticassets.azureedge.net:80 success
Auto Tunnel BackgroundTaskHost.exe, pid=10156 success
```

The first line seems to be a connection to our website's CDN. The second, I'm not too sure about.

Overall, what do these two outputs signify? What could be going on? Should I be alarmed, or is this an empty threat?

It would be great to get an explanation of the hacking attempt here (if it was).

Comment: Google search finds forums.goha.ru/showthread_82_1_t646515 and https://forums.planetcoaster.com/showthread.php/19489-Planet-Coaster-Winter-Update-Update-notes?styleid=8 which suggest that these might be standard game engine messages.  Limited data, in Russian, but maybe helpful.

Comment: To me this all looks off, connecting to anything normal on port 80 is nothing to brag about and I'd find it very strange if you were using BackgroundTaskHost.exe on an ubuntu server. Did you check to see if the PID is actually in use on the system? Because if he says he somehow interacted with pid 10156 and it doesn't even exist on the system. I'd be a lot less worried.

Comment: I did a quick `pmap <PID> | head -1`, it yields nothing. It could be that the person posted something she/he did on their own (Windows) computer. Connecting to my CDN on port 80 also doesn't look like a big feat like rightly pointed out. I suppose there's nothing more to investigate here.